# No kernel named was found. First SYCL app

Tags: intel-oneapi, sycl

I'm trying to code my first SYCL app. Just some falling sand.
The details aren't important. just if cell has sand and cell beneath is empty move the sand, else bottom left or bottom right or if no room do nothing.
I don't have anything to visualize the particles yet, but that's for later.

```
#pragma warning (push, 0)
#include <CL/sycl.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#pragma warning (pop)

constexpr int WIDTH = 1024;
constexpr int HEIGHT = 1024;

class FallingPowder {
public:
  static int simulate(sycl::accessor<int, 2, sycl::access::mode::read_write,
                                     sycl::access::target::global_buffer>
                          grid_accessor,
                      sycl::item<2> item) {
    size_t x = item.get_id(0);
    size_t y = item.get_id(1);

    int current_cell = grid_accessor[{x, y}];
    int below_cell = grid_accessor[{x, y - 1}];
    int below_left_cell = grid_accessor[{x - 1, y - 1}];
    int below_right_cell = grid_accessor[{x + 1, y - 1}];

    // Check if the current cell has a particle and the cell below is empty.
    if (current_cell == 1) {
      if (below_cell == 0) {
        // Move the particle down.
        grid_accessor[{x, y - 1}] = 1;
        grid_accessor[{x, y}] = 0;
      } else if (below_left_cell == 0 && below_right_cell == 0) {
        // Move the particle down.
        if (rand() % 2) {
          grid_accessor[{x - 1, y - 1}] = 1;
        } else {
          grid_accessor[{x + 1, y - 1}] = 1;
        }
        grid_accessor[{x, y}] = 0;
      } else if (below_left_cell == 0) {
        grid_accessor[{x - 1, y - 1}] = 1;
        grid_accessor[{x, y}] = 0;
      } else if (below_right_cell == 0) {
        grid_accessor[{x + 1, y - 1}] = 1;
        grid_accessor[{x, y}] = 0;
      }
    }

    return grid_accessor[{x, y}];
  }
};

int main() {
  sycl::queue q(sycl::default_selector{});
  std::vector<int> grid(WIDTH * HEIGHT, 0);
  for (int x = (WIDTH / 2) - 50; x < (WIDTH / 2) + 50; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
      grid[x + y * WIDTH] = 1;
    }
  }

  sycl::buffer<int, 2> grid_buffer(grid.data(), sycl::range<2>(WIDTH, HEIGHT));

  for (int t = 0; t < 1000; t++) {
    q.submit([&](sycl::handler &cgh) {
      auto grid_accessor =
          grid_buffer.get_access<sycl::access::mode::read_write>(cgh);

      cgh.parallel_for<FallingPowder>(
          sycl::range<2>(WIDTH, HEIGHT - 1), [=](sycl::item<2> item) {
            grid_accessor[item] = FallingPowder::simulate(grid_accessor, item);
          });
    });
  }

  q.wait_and_throw();

  return 0;
}
```

It compiles fine, but when I run it I get:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'sycl::_V1::runtime_error'
  what():  No kernel named  was found -46 (PI_ERROR_INVALID_KERNEL_NAME)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've looked at a few tutorials and don't exactly get what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

We are unable to reproduce your issue on Intel UHD Graphics device using DPCPP compiler/Intel C++ compiler with the below commands:

```
icpx -fsycl file.cpp
```

or

```
dpcpp file.cpp
```

Could you please let us know which hardware and compiler you are using to compile the program?
Here's another suggestion which might work. Could you please try with -fno-sycl-unnamed-lambda which disables unnamed SYCL lambda kernels that are defined using the below command.

```
icpx -fsycl -fno-sycl-unnamed-lambda file.cpp
```

There is more info on `-fno-sycl-unamed-lambda` in the [Intel® oneAPI DPC++/C++ Compiler Developer Guide and Reference](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/dpcpp-cpp-compiler/developer-guide-reference/2023-1/fsycl-unnamed-lambda.html).